# TYPO3 Object of type xxx\\yyy\\Domain\\Model\\User with identity \"1\" not found."

Tags: typo3-8.x, persistent-storage

I want to add a custom FrontendUser to a group (not related to frontend group) in the groups controller.

Somehow Extbase can find my group by the uid but not the user I specified by uid.

My action in th GroupController is:

```
/**
  * action addUser
  * @param \xxx\Yyy\Domain\Model\Group $group
  * @param \xxx\Yyy\Domain\Model\User $user
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function addUserAction(\xxx\Yyy\Domain\Model\Group $group, \xxx\Yyy\Domain\Model\User $user)
  {
    $group.addUser($user);
    return "ok";

  }
```

My error exception is:

```
{"error":"TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Property\\Exception\\TargetNotFoundException #1297933823: Object of type xxx\\Yyy\\Domain\\Model\\User with identity \"1\" not found."
,"trace":["TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Property\\TypeConverter\\PersistentObjectConverter->fetchObjectFromPersistence(2 Arguments)"
,"TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Property\\TypeConverter\\PersistentObjectConverter->convertFrom(4 Arguments)"
,"TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Property\\PropertyMapper->doMapping(4 Arguments)"
,"TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Property\\PropertyMapper->convert(3 Arguments)"
,"TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Controller\\Argument->setValue(1 Arguments)"
,"TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Controller\\AbstractController->mapRequestArgumentsToControllerArguments()"
,"TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Controller\\ActionController->processRequest(2 Arguments)"
,"TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Dispatcher->dispatch(2 Arguments)"
,"TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Web\\FrontendRequestHandler->handleRequest()"
,"TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Core\\Bootstrap->handleRequest()"
,"TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Core\\Bootstrap->run(2 Arguments)"
,"xxx\\Yyy\\Rest\\Helper->callExtbasePlugin(6 Arguments)"
,"xxx\\Yyy\\Rest\\GroupHandler->xxx\\Yyy\\Rest\\{closure}(1 Arguments)"
,"Cundd\\Rest\\Router\\Route->process(1 Arguments)"
,"Cundd\\Rest\\Router\\Router->dispatch(1 Arguments)"
,"Cundd\\Rest\\Router\\ResultConverter->dispatch(1 Arguments)"
,"Cundd\\Rest\\Dispatcher->callHandler(1 Arguments)"
,"Cundd\\Rest\\Dispatcher->getCachedResponseOrCallHandler(2 Arguments)"
,"Cundd\\Rest\\Dispatcher->dispatch(2 Arguments)"
,"Cundd\\Rest\\Dispatcher->processRequest(2 Arguments)"
,"Cundd\\Rest\\BootstrapDispatcher->processRequest(2 Arguments)"
,"call_user_func_array(2 Arguments)"
,"TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\Dispatcher->dispatch(2 Arguments)"
,"TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Http\\EidRequestHandler->dispatch(1 Arguments)"
,"TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Http\\EidRequestHandler->handleRequest(1 Arguments)"
,"TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Core\\Bootstrap->handleRequest(1 Arguments)"
,"TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Http\\Application->run()"
,"{closure}()"
,"require(1 Arguments)"]}
```

For debugging purpose I added the an initializeAction:

```
public function initializeAddUserAction()
  {
    return var_dump($_POST);
  }
```

The result is:

```
array(1) {
  ["tx_yyy_jsonapi"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["controller"]=>
    string(5) "Group"
    ["action"]=>
    string(7) "addUser"
    ["group"]=>
    int(1)
    ["user"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the group resolving fine but the user not? I'm using TYPO3 8.7 with the rest extension in verion 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fe_users` had the field `tx_extbase_type` set to 0. It works if I set it to `Tx_Yyy_User`. So the problem was that I made no diffence between a regular FrontendUser and my custom frontend user.

Comment: Which else reason could this error have? For me it does not occur for fe_users, but for a own custom table/model which I want to handle in a backend module.